# Ternary operator won't return HTML

Tags: twig, symfony4

I would like to use the ternary operator of Twig but it shows me the HTML tags as text.

```
{{ (sender.firstName or sender.lastName) ? "<strong>#{sender.firstName}  #{sender.lastName}</strong>" : '<strong>Unknown</strong>' }}
```

The result is `<strong>My Name</strong>` but it should be **My Name**.

Comment: There really isn't a reason to use the html in the ternary itself, you're always wrapping it's result with `strong` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the `raw` as the output is not marked as safe when concatenating `html` with `twig`

```
{{ (sender.firstName or sender.lastName ? "<strong>#{sender.firstName}  #{sender.lastName}</strong>" : "<strong>Unknown</strong>")|raw }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/c4otei)